Вызов инлайн клавиатуры в ответ на сообщение
Есть телеграм канал модерируемый ботом, с помощью которого админ может временно банить пользователей чата ответом на сообщение и командой /ban.
Для этого сначала нужно нажать "ответ", затем в строку ввести команду /ban, что не слишком удобно.
Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы при ответе админа на комментарий пользователя инлайн клавиатура вызывалась сразу и была бы видна только админу чата. Примеры кода не нашел.
Или клавиатуру можно сделать только для бота и вызывается она только отдельной командой?

Насколько я знаю вызвать инлайн клавиатуру можно только отправив команду боту. Могу предложить такое решение: в BotFather добавить команду /ban (она будет видна всем пользователям), в коде делать проверку: если id == такой-то, то бан, иначе ответь недостаточно прав. Но так как команда короткая лучше ее не добавлять

Если вызывать клавиатуру в группе, то она будет видна всем, а не только админу. Можно передавать ее в боте в лс с админом. Только не очень понятна логика. При каких ответах реагировать должен бот?

К сожалению да, вызвать инлайн клавиатуру можно только отправив команду боту. А я хотел, чтобы клавиатура вызывалась одновременно с ответом админа на комментарий, и далее для админа было две кнопки: бан и ответить.
